# How to determine in Pandas which column row values result in final true value given an equation

Tags: python, pandas

Is there anyway to determine which row values in a column make the final expression true and then outputting those values?

Example:

Equation
a && b || (c && d)
if
a = T, b = T, c = F, d = T
then the output should produce:
True Values: a, b
False Values: c, d

Is this possible in pandas or python?

Answer (score 1):

```
df[((df["column_a"]==True) & (df["column_b"]==True)) | ((df["column_a"]==False) & (df["column_d"]==True))]
```

I guess this is what you're tying to say, but if you're trying to do something based on individual data points in the respective columns then you have to use for loop(s) depending on the problem.

Comment: What if the values changed, and the equation was much longer. Is there no way of automating it without inputting the values directly?

Comment: If it's a recurring problem, then you can create a function but if it's a dynamic problem, I don't think so we can automate. To be fair, it really depends on what the problem is.